# Trying to understand Java RSA key size

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

The key generator was initilized with a size of 1024, so why the printed sizes are 635 and 162?

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

public class TEST {

    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();

    System.out.println("Size = " + privateKey.getEncoded().length);
    System.out.println("Size = " + publicKey.getEncoded().length);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

RSA keys are made of Modulus and Exponent. The key size refers to the bits in modulus. So even without any encoding overhead, you will need more than 128 bytes to store 1024-bit keys.

getEncoded() returns ASN.1 DER encoded objects. The private key even contains CRT parameters so it's very large.

To get key size, do something like this,

```
System.out.println("Key size = " + publicKey.getModulus().bitLength());
```

Here are the relevant ASN.1 objects,

```
RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    version           Version,
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
    privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
    prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
    prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
    exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
    exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
    coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
    otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
}


RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

Comment: For others finding this in the future on google, the class `sun.security.util.KeyUtil` has a `getKeySize` function that takes a Key, and based on what algorithm it was created with, uses different functions to return the appropriate number.  For the OP's "RSA" keypair, it uses `getModulus().bitLength()`.  (I know the `sun.security` package is not meant to be used by programmers, but [you can see the source from a recent version of the JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/util/KeyUtil.java) as an example.)

Comment: Not quite. JCE uses generic encodings that can handle multiple algorithms -- SubjectPublicKeyInfo from X.509/PKIX and PrivateKeyInfo from PKCS8/rfc5208, see the javadoc for `java.security.Key` -- which (both) include an AlgorithmIdentifier specifying the OID for RSA _plus_ (for RSA) the PKCS1 structures you quote, wrapped in BIT STRING and OCTET STRING respectively. This adds (even) more overhead.

Answer (score 6):

First hint: `1024 bits = 128 bytes`

Second hint: `privateKey.getEncoded()` returns an `encoded` representation (i.e. not raw).

Comment: The "key size" means different things for different coders, and is not trivially related to the key. In the case of RSA it's the size of the modulus. (You should use getModulus() ) See ZZ Coder's answer.

Comment: there's something wrong, the getModulus return a number of 309 digits. If this means the size is 309, its still not what a had setted (1024).

Comment: third hint : 1024 * Log10(2) = 308.25 => 1024 bits ~ 309 decimal digits