# Issue exchanging symmetric keys using RSA with encoded size larger than block size

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm working on implementing a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) for a project that involves a large amount of cross platform secure network communication. In this instance, the communicating parties are running .NET and Java, so I'm using the provided cryptosystem frameworks from each stack respectively.

I can successfully generate keypairs of the same size (4096 bit) on both of the systems, and have successfully transmitted the keys and loaded them into the remote systems so that I can encrypt with the public key of the remote system on each machine.

I then generate symmetric keys and IVs on both of the systems, and am trying to exchange the symmetric keys between the two systems. **Unfortunately, after I've encoded the key and IV information in my custom communication protocol, the data is larger than the key size** (not by much, it's typically in the 600-1000 byte area, but still over the ~500 byte limit for my key size).

My solution to this was splitting the data, and running the RSA encryption over the blocks of the appropriate size. However, I don't know what size to be splitting the blocks into, as I've been hearing many different formulas, such as:

- `((KEY_SIZE) / 8) - 11`
- `((KEY_SIZE) / 8) - 42`

However, whenever I encrypt information with the first block size (`((KEY_SIZE) / 8) - 11`, which comes out to 501 bytes), [RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(byte[] data, bool fOAEP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx) throws a `Bad Length!` error. Whenever I use the second block size (`((KEY_SIZE) / 8) - 42`), it successfully processes the block, but it gives  me an output of 513 bytes (it seems any input of between 0-500 bytes gets padded up to this 513 byte value, which I assume is [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) doing its job), which is too large to decrypt using my 4096 bit key according to my Java cryptosystem (`javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 512 bytes`). If this is the case, why is the .NET cryptosystem giving me a 513 byte output with OAEP, if it cannot be decrypted at this size?

My .NET RSA encryption implementation is below .`_rsaProvider` has been initialized with the valid remote public key. `RSA_BUFFER_SIZE` is a constant relative to the `KEY_SIZE` (which is 4096) (doesn't work if `RSA_BUFFER_SIZE` is 501, but works for 496 and below it seems, as explained above):

```
        byte[] block;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read = 0;
            while (read < data.Length)
            {
                block = new byte[RSA_BUFFER_SIZE]; 
                int toRead = Math.Min(data.Length - read, block.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, read, block, 0, toRead);
                read += toRead;
                byte[] decrypted = _rsaProvider.Encrypt(block, true);
                stream.Write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
            }
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
```

And here is the Java implementation of decrypting this information (`RSA_BUFFER_SIZE` uses the same logic size as above with the same keysize):

```
    byte[] block;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int read = 0;
    while (read < data.length) {
        block = new byte[RSA_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int toRead = Math.min(data.length - read, block.length);
        System.arraycopy(data, read, block, 0, toRead);
        read += toRead;
        output.write(_localAsymmetricCipher.doFinal(block));
    }
    byte[] ret = output.toByteArray();
    output.close();
    return ret;
```

Is there an issue with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it actually WAS the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729893/data-encrypted-in-c-sharp-is-1-byte-too-long-to-be-decrypted-in-java). My public key generation on the Java system had a leading zero in the modulus BigInteger. Solved by cutting off the first byte.